# Under Gtk+/Glib are there any utility functions, where we can read and write config File?

Tags: gtk, glib

I have a config file in which I have keys and values, like this:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

So is there any utility functions in Gtk/Glib that can read this file and retrieve the value corresponds to key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

glib has a *Key-value-file-parser*. It supports a syntax similar to the better known INI files.

Here's a link to [the documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html)

Comment: See new doc link: https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.KeyFile.html#methods